# I have a Discord.js bot that is not sending a scheduled message

Tags: discord.js, node-cron

I have a Discord bot that is scheduled to send a message every 1st of July (and some other stuff). Yet, it's not sending the message, but yet it is sending the other stuff. Thanks in advance.

This is the specific lines where it doesn't send the message:

`cron.schedule('*0 0 0 1 7 *', () => {`
`client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID').send('Happy 1st of July!');`

`});`

Comment: did you mean to use the cronjob `0 0 1 7 *`? ( “At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 in July.” )

Comment: yes, i didn't notice that! thank you so much!

Comment: Please accept the answer I have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct cronjob is `0 0 1 7 *`. (“At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 in July.”)